# Tizen 3.0 on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, tizen

I'm trying to install Tizen OS on Raspberry Pi. I've found various guides, as per link below but they're fairly complex for someone with a Windows / SQL background.

https://wiki.tizen.org/Guide_for_the_Raspberry_PI_3_with_Tizen_4.0#How_to_flash_platform_image_for_Tizen

I have RPI 3 Model B and I would like either Tizen 3.0 or 4.0.

Does anyone have details of a pre-built image I could fuse directly to the SD card for this config?

Answer (score 1):

Different release(s) provide developers with the Tizen kernel, device drivers, middleware subsystems, and Web/Native APIs.
Such as Tizen 4.0 M3, Tizen 5.0 M1, Tizen 4.0 M2, Tizen 3.0 M3, Tizen 4.0 M1, Tizen 3.0 M2,
Tizen 3.0, Tizen 3.0 Milestones, Tizen RT 1.0 M1 etc.

Check out release details for different version e.g. Mobile,Wearable, TV .
Additionally check "How to flash to a device" section getting idea on how to flash Tizen OS.

See these links:

1. https://source.tizen.org/release/tizen-4.0-m2
2. https://source.tizen.org/documentation/reference/flash-device

Comment: Hi Yasin - thanks for this, seems like a good source. I'm reading the "How to Flash a Device" section. Would the Raspberry Pi be a TM1 device, or a PQ or 210 device? None of these seem obviously the right choice....

Comment: Thanks Yasin, that does add some useful extra detail. It's not obvious which route is the correct one for Raspberry Pi - however, I think the best option is to try it. I will give some of these scenarios a go and report back here how successful they are.